# warning cannot bind argument to parameter 'fast packagereference' because it is an empty string

Tags: powershell, docker

I am trying to install docker on Windows Server 2016. Whenever I run `FindContainerImage` command on powershell it shows:

```
WARNING: Cannot bind the argument to parameter 'fastPackageReference' because it is an empty string.
WARNING: The property 'version' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
WARNING: The property 'Name" cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
WARNING: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\ContainerImage\ContainerImageGallery_ContainerImageSearchIndex.txt' because it does not exists.
WARNING: Http.Getsync did not return successful status code. Status Code: NotFound, The specified resource does not exist.
```

Please Help me out!

Comment: i cannot find any reference to that `FindContainerImage` command. are you sure that you have posted it correctly?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I think OP might be referring to `Find-ContainerImage` which comes with [this package provider](https://github.com/PowerShell/ContainerProvider). Hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the full command being invoked though

Comment: Please post the full command (including any arguments) you're running

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - ah! that makes sense ...i was unable to find any link to the one that the OP posted. [*grin*]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjWFILSvhCs ----- this is the reference I used. Firsta I run "Install-PackageProvider ContainerImage -Force" for base OS image. After I ran "Find-Container Image" but couldnot see any options.
(Sorry for not responding quickly)

Answer (score 7):

I am able to figure this out. I followed the steps below to install docker on my windows server 2016. Thank you so much for respondig- **Lee_Dailey,  Mathias R. Jessen**

Run powershell with Administrative privilege while doing this and update your machine.

1. [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
   Install-Module PowerShellGet -RequiredVersion 2.2.4 -SkipPublisherCheck
2. Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery –Force
3. Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -verbose
4. get-service docker
5. start-service docker
6. docker version
7. docker pull microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-sac2016